# Как прокрутить чат бота с юзером?

Tags: telegram-bot

допустим есть чат бота с юзером с N сообщений.
Я бы хотел реализовать что бы при клике пользователем на калбек кнопку в старом сообщении что бы сообщение удалилось, а пользователю пришло новое сообщение и чат с ботом проскролился к новому сообщению. Есть идеи как реализовать скролинг к нужному сообщению в чате с ботом мб я что то в документации пропустил?